# Nexus Docker Registries: blob unknown: blob unknown to registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry, nexus3

I have 3 docker registries in my nexus repo: docker-hosted, docker-proxy, docker-group

docker-hosted is a registry that I can push images into it.
docker-proxy is used when I want to pull images from the docker hub and used as a cache for the docker hub.
I grouped these 2 registries in a docker-group repo.

I use this config in my Nginx so I can easily push and pull the docker images from my nexus repo.

```
    server {
        listen   *:443 default_server ssl;

.........................

        location ~ ^/(v1|v2)/[^/]+/?[^/]+/blobs/ {
            if ($request_method ~* (POST|PUT|DELETE|PATCH|HEAD) ) {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /repository/docker-hosted/$1 last;
            }
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /repository/docker-group/$1 last;
        }

        location ~ ^/(v1|v2)/ {
            if ($request_method ~* (POST|PUT|DELETE|PATCH) ) {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /repository/docker-hosted/$1 last;
            }
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /repository/docker-group/$1 last;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://nexus:8081/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
        }
    }
```

I have a simple dockerfile:

```
FROM mynexusrepo.com/python:3.7.1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --default-timeout=1000 --no-cache-dir
COPY . /code/
CMD python /code/manage.py makemigrations && python /code/manage.py migrate && python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:666
```

when I push this to registry I get this error:

```
cacb7942af06: Layer already exists
26636c98b4ec: Layer already exists
11fb6501ac00: Layer already exists
77ec1bf82c58: Layer already exists
c660d5dc256a: Layer already exists
9e701d0e0edd: Layer already exists
3294fae58626: Layer already exists
9e89ea4aeda3: Layer already exists
e02b32b1ff99: Layer already exists
f75e64f96dbc: Layer already exists
8f7ee6d76fd9: Layer already exists
c23711a84ad4: Layer already exists
90d1009ce6fe: Layer already exists
errors:
blob unknown: blob unknown to registry
blob unknown: blob unknown to registry
blob unknown: blob unknown to registry
blob unknown: blob unknown to registry
blob unknown: blob unknown to registry
blob unknown: blob unknown to registry
blob unknown: blob unknown to registry
blob unknown: blob unknown to registry
blob unknown: blob unknown to registry
```

nexus log:

```
Manifest refers to missing layer: sha256:dd7cc9ace2427e64037752916207e90ff203948d45fff8eb41cd250413c27f10 for: ....
```

I found that the missing layers are for mynexusrepo.com/python:3.7.1 . so I create a new python:3.7.1 with the tag mynexusrepo.com/python:3.7.1 and push it to my repo.

I check the nexus and find out that I can't reference the layer from docker-proxy to docker-hosted.

is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: what nexus repo manager version are you running?

Comment: @NoamYizraeli Sonatype Nexus Repository ManagerOSS 3.32.0-03

Comment: have you previously use version 30/31 (and its minor versions)?

Comment: @NoamYizraeli I don't remember the exact version. but I have this problem with the old version too.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this nexus bug [NEXUS-28247](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-28247) caused a similar issue for us around docker images.

After checking nexus developer forums and speaking directly to the company the only resolution was:

saving what was possible to fetch from the private nexus repo --> reverting to an earlier backup --> recreating images by CICD if possible.

I know this doesn't resolve your current situation but at least it explains the **why** of it.

under version [3.32.0 release notes](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/release-notes/2021-release-notes/nexus-repository-3.32.0-release-notes) they mentioned the bug fix

The forum in question [nexus-developers](https://gitter.im/sonatype/nexus-developers?at=59f758a232e080696e439b9f)

Comment: no, it's not about the GC task. I test it with a new image and it happens again. I don't think this bug is related to my issue.

Comment: It can happen with new images too, since the image blobs are misplaced, placing new blobs sometimes results in the same issue

Comment: I can see the image blob exists and even I can pull it.

Comment: the problem is not primarily in the blob's existence but the reference to it in the repo's db